# Hide a header in a div class which is part of another class

Tags: css

Hi I have this div class and would like to hide its h4 header only which forms part of another class.
I tried this but it's not working

```css
.pxSearchfield .lscf-sidebar-heading {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pxSearchField ng-scope" ng-switch-when="search">
  <h4 class="lscf-sidebar-heading ng-binding">Search</h4>
  <!-- ngIf: allPostsCount <= 300 && 1 === pluginSettings.generalSettings.instant_search && true !== actionSettings.filtersOnly --><input live-search="" ng-if="allPostsCount <= 300 &amp;&amp; 1 === pluginSettings.generalSettings.instant_search &amp;&amp; true !== actionSettings.filtersOnly" type="text" ng-blur="buildLocationOnBlur()" ng-class="{ 'px-focus' : pxsearch != '' &amp;&amp; pxsearch != undefined }"
    ng-model="pxsearch" class="lscf-live-search-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty" placeholder="Search" style="">
  <!-- end ngIf: allPostsCount <= 300 && 1 === pluginSettings.generalSettings.instant_search && true !== actionSettings.filtersOnly -->

  <!-- ngIf: allPostsCount > 300 || 0 === pluginSettings.generalSettings.instant_search || true === actionSettings.filtersOnly  -->

  <hr class="silver">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Class names are case sensitive.

Ensure the class name you are targeting in your css selector matches the class name in the html class attribute eg `pxSearchField` vs `pxSearchfield`

```css
.pxSearchField .lscf-sidebar-heading {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pxSearchField ng-scope" ng-switch-when="search">
  <h4 class="lscf-sidebar-heading">Search</h4>
  <input placeholder="Search" style="">
  <hr class="silver">
</div>
```